# In TESTRIGOR - Public Opensource -> How to delete test case and it's execution result?

Tags: testrigor

I have created & executed test case in the Testrigor public opensource account. Now **I want to delete that test case & it's execution result and test suite  can someone please help me and let me know?**

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your test cases have two Delete buttons. One way is to open the Quick actions dropdown on right side of the case, and click `Delete`. The other way is to expand the test case in to the view with screenshots with the down arrow on the right of the test case status and run time. Then click `Delete` on the far right. In addition, there is also a way to delete cases in bulk using the `Select multiple` button.